# Haskell function about even and odd numbers

Tags: function, haskell, numbers

I'm new to Haskell, started learning a couple of days ago and I have a question on a function I'm trying to make.

I want to make a function that verifies if *x* is a factor of *n* (ex: 375 has these factors: 1, 3, 5, 15, 25, 75, 125 and 375), then removes the 1 and then the number itself and finally verifies if the number of odd numbers in that list is equal to the number of even numbers!

I thought of making a functions like so to calculate the first part:

```
factor n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod`x == 0]
```

But if I put this on the prompt it will say `Not in scope 'n'`. The idea was to input a number like 375 so it would calculate the list. What I'm I doing wrong? I've seen functions being put in the prompt like this, in books.

Then to take the elements I spoke of I was thinking of doing tail and then init to the list. You think it's a good idea?

And finally I thought of making an if statement to verify the last part. For example, in Java, we'd make something like:

```
(x % 2 == 0)? even++ : odd++; // (I'm a beginner to Java as well)
```

and then if even = odd then it would say that all conditions were verified (we had a quantity of even numbers equal to the odd numbers)

But in Haskell, as variables are immutable, how would I do the something++ thing?

Thanks for any help you can give :)

Comment: You have to use recursion. http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This small function does everything that you are trying to achieve:

```
f n = length evenFactors == length oddFactors
  where evenFactors = [x | x <- [2, 4..(n-1)], n `mod` x == 0]
        oddFactors  = [x | x <- [3, 5..(n-1)], n `mod` x == 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

If the "command line" is ghci, then you need to

```
let factor n = [x | x <- [2..(n-1)], n `mod` x == 0]
```

In this particular case you don't need to range [1..n] only to drop 1 and n - range from 2 to (n-1) instead.

The you can simply use partition to split the list of divisors using a boolean predicate:

```
import Data.List
partition odd $ factor 10
```

In order to learn how to write a function like `partition`, study recursion.

For example:

```
partition p = foldr f ([],[]) where
  f x ~(ys,ns) | p x = (x:ys,ns)
  f x ~(ys,ns) = (ys, x:ns)
```

(Here we need to pattern-match the tuples lazily using "~", to ensure the pattern is not evaluated before the tuple on the right is constructed).

Simple counting can be achieved even simpler:

```
let y = factor 375
(length $ filter odd y) == (length y - (length $ filter odd y))
```

Comment: So instead of the partition, I could just aplly the last part right? "let y = factor 375
(length $ filter odd y) == (length y - (length $ filter odd y))" ? And thanks for your answer :D

Comment: yes, but there can be greater cost than partitioning, because we traverse y twice (once for filter, once for length) and traverse the filtered list once; whereas partition will traverse y twice (once to partition, once both partitions to work out the length). I've edited to pattern-match the pairs lazily, which is necessary for partitioning long lists.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file source.hs, then from ghci command line call `:l source` to load the functions defined in source.hs.

To solve your problem this may be a solution following your steps:

```
-- computers the factors of n, gets the tail (strips 1)
-- the filter functions removes n from the list
factor n = filter (/= n) (tail [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0])

-- checks if the number of odd and even factors is equal
oe n = let factors = factor n in 
           length (filter odd factors) == length (filter even factors)
```

Calling `oe 10` returns `True`, `oe 15` returns `False`

Comment: Focusing on the idea: mytest n = length (evenNumbers (chopEnds (factors n))) == length (oddNumbers (chopEnds (factors n)))

Comment: @pNre Just one thing I don't quite get, in this part: oe n = let factors = factor n in, what does it do? I mean, what does 'in' do? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sure [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be) will help

Comment: 'let' and 'in' just give another name to some expression, so you don't have to type so much. You can also use it to make something more clear. Another example:
mytest n = let choppedFactors = chopEnds (factors n) in length (evenNumbers choppedFactors) == length (oddNumbers choppedFactors)

Just read http://learnyouahaskell.com/ Its all in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
(x % 2 == 0)? even++ : odd++;
```

We have at `Data.List` a `partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` function

So we can divide odds like

```
> let (odds,evens) = partition odd [1..]

> take 10 odds
 [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
> take 10 evens
 [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal fix for your `factor` attempt using comprehensions:

```
factor nn = [x | n <- [1..nn], x <- [1..n], n `mod`x == 0]
```